# Is there a specific way to perform string manipulation in jMeter?

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I have recorded a test script and extracted a string using the Regular Expression Extraction and got it's value to be (reportID):- /api/application/GetAsyncTaskProgress/fa38d781-c679-4e15-959f-1b953e3873f4

I want to extract the value 'fa38d781-c679-4e15-959f-1b953e3873f4' from the above expression.

I tried to extract the value using the following JavaScript function:-

${__javaScript(var testString= "${reportID}".split('/'); test = testString[testString.length - 1]; return test;  ,returnID)}

However, it does not return any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below snippet. This will yield the reportID.

```
${__javaScript(var testString= "${reportID}".split('/'); testString[testString.length - 1]; , returnID)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your regular expression is not very well designed, I believe you could get this `fa38d781-c679-4e15-959f-1b953e3873f4` from the response directly.

Anyway, there is a possibility to use [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) for extracting a value **from the JMeter Variable** so if you have `reportID` JMeter Variable with the value of `/api/application/GetAsyncTaskProgress/fa38d781-c679-4e15-959f-1b953e3873f4` you can use the following Regular Expression Extractor to get this `fa38d781-c679-4e15-959f-1b953e3873f4` value:

[image]

Also be aware [that since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and __groovy() function for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) because [Groovy has the best performance among all JMeter scripting languages](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/), the relevant __groovy() function would be something like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('reportID').substring(vars.get('reportID').lastIndexOf('/') + 1),returnID)}
```